# mysql price range with or in range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `products` with price and sale columns (float 8,2).
Products without sale price will have values as shown below.
`price` 13.20
`sale` 0.00

And products with sale price as:
`price` 10.00
`sale` 08.00

I'm trying to get all products where `price` is between $min and $max or `sale` is between $min and $max.

```
 select * from `products`  where
```

( (`price` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 22.00) OR (`sale` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 22.00) )
  and `status` = 1 and `sold` = 0 and `deleted` = 0 order by `id` desc limit 12

But this is not working? Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Ok i tested this one -

```
 select * from `products`  where
```

( (`price` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 22.00) OR (`sale` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 22.00) )
  and `status` = 1 and `sold` = 0 and `deleted` = 0 order by `id` desc limit 12

Problem i found that it works if min price is like for example 0.01 but if min price is 0.00 i get products with no price limits. Why query hates 0.00 min price? oO

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you forgot braces between OR substatements:

```
select * from `products`
where (
    (`price` >= $min AND `price` <= $max) OR (`sale` >= $min AND `sale` <= $max)
) and `status` = 1 and `sold` = 0 and `deleted` = 0 order by `id` desc limit 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Added `BETWEEN min AND max`

```
  select * from `products`  where       
  ( (`price` BETWEEN $min AND $max) OR (`sale` BETWEEN $min AND $max) )       
  and `status` = 1 and `sold` = 0 and `deleted` = 0 order by `id` desc limit 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

```
select * from `products` where (price BETWEEN $min AND $max) OR `sale` >= $min AND `sale` <= $max) and `status` = 1 and `sold` = 0 and `deleted` = 0 order by `id` desc limit 12
```